# Why doesn't the compiler work for C language using Visual Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

I just wrote my first program using C language in Visual Code. I don't have any errors but the program won't compile. At the terminal, I'm typing clang cardsa.c. It's giving me errors that clang doesn't exist. I tried typing clang -o and got the same error that clang doesn't exist. How do I compile this?

I also tried coding this in CodeBlocks but when I ran the program I kept getting errors that the program needed to Build first, which I clicked and it didn't do anything. I tried this several times, clicking on Build and when it failed after multiple attempts, I switched to Visual Code.

Comment: I think you need to read a few more tutorials on how to compile things.

Comment: Your last sentence will get your question closed. Do not ask for software recommendations. Please delete that part. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Rob: Asking whether there **is** some other software, that is, a question about **existence**, is a matter of fact and is not off topic. Asking for a **recommendation** is a matter of opinion and is off topic.

Comment: If you are on macOS you  need to install xcode tools to get clang.

Comment: Look like you just need to install a compiler, google could probably help you

Comment: @EricPostpischil And you don't think anyone would provide recommendations then? You say tomato...etc.

Comment: You probably have some simple problem, with Codeblocks on Windows for example try going into settings, Compiler, and looking through the various options (like 'toolchain executables, search directories) to make sure your program is in the right directory.  See also Settings-Environment-check and set file associations... Or just try compiling with GCC directly from the WSL/Linux bash command line (best learning setup I think). Or take your code over to godbolt.org and run in compiler explorer.

Comment: @Rob: An answer being off topic is grounds for deleting the answer, not for closing the question. We should not block people from asking for or receiving useful information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You need to read the rules I linked to.

Comment: @Rob: The rules say  questions asking to “recommend or find” software are off-topic. I already explained the distinction between questions about recommendations and questions about existence. Questions ask to “find” software are also different from a question about existence, as asking somebody to find something is a request for work, whereas merely asking about existence is a request for information.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to compile would be:

```
clang -o EXEC_NAME source.c ... (any other .c files) ...
```

Check if it's installed by typing on the command line:
`clang --version`: If `clang`doesn't exist, you would need to install it, see
[installation instructions](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macclion/clang.html)